# How should I distribute my licence points?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I've started playing through FF12 for the first time and I'm not really sure how to 'level' my characters.

Is it worth specialising in one particular type of weapon/armour or will I gain enough points as I go along to be able to switch between different types? If changing to different equipment types is the way to go, how do I know what to skill up for different characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between the characters is pretty negligible, so pick a couple characters you like and then equip them with whatever weapons you like.

Distribute the license points however you wish, you should get enough by the end to max every ones grid.

However, do take note of the quickening locations on the board. Each of them can only be unlocked with 1 character, so I advise just picking which character will go toward which ones early.

Comment: Unless you're drowning in License Points, don't bother spending LP to unlock equipment that you don't have.